# Best Algorithm to avoid nested loops without Brute Force approach

Tags: java, algorithm, nested-loops, brute-force

I want to make this method run as fast as possible.

```
int[] p = new int[] {1,4,4,5,1,3,6};
int[] q = new int[] {2,1,3,1,6,4,3};
int k =4.
void nestLoop(){
 for(int i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < p.length; j++){
       //code continues 
       // inside here...
       //This approach 
        // takes a longer 
         //time to finish 
         // executing. I need a better algorithm

      }


  }
}
```

To be clearer; at q[0], p = 1,  since 1 is less than q[0], choose 1, and p[4] is also lower, choose 1; hence the answer when it is q[0] are 1 and 1 : but because 1 and 1 are two ints, they are not equal to k = 4, then return 0. If the answer had been 1, 1,1,1 then the number is 4 which is equal to k. [1,1,1,1] will be returned. The same for other q and so on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219316/discussion-on-question-by-show-young-soyinka-best-algorithm-to-avoid-nested-loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using Java Streams:

```
package javaapplication3;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] p = new int[] {1,4,4,5,1,3,6};
        int[] q = new int[] {2,1,3,1,6,4,3};
        int[][] results = new int[q.length][]; // Array of arrays to store results
        int k =4;
        
        // For each element q[i], execute in parallel
        IntStream.range(0, q.length).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            final int qi = q[i];
            // Get first k elements of p <= q[i]
            results[i] = Arrays.stream(p).filter(v -> v <= qi).limit(k).toArray();            
        });
        
        for(int i=0; i<q.length; i++) {
            int[] result = results[i];
            System.out.print("Values less or equal than " + q[i] + ": {");
            for (int v : result)
                System.out.print(" " + v);
            System.out.println(" }");
        }

    }    
}
```

Output:

```
Values less or equal than 2: { 1 1 }
Values less or equal than 1: { 1 1 }
Values less or equal than 3: { 1 1 3 }
Values less or equal than 1: { 1 1 }
Values less or equal than 6: { 1 4 4 5 }
Values less or equal than 4: { 1 4 4 1 }
Values less or equal than 3: { 1 1 3 }
```

Note: You can optionally sort p which will improve performance if p is large and k is small.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is basically still exactly the same algorithm, just using streams, right? I guess it's fine if OP just wants to "avoid the (explicit) loop", but it's probably not any faster.

Comment: @tobias_k You are correct. I mentioned this to the OP in one of my comments. That said, I provided the possibility to use all cores. Moreover, in the absence of information of the relative sizes of p, q and k we are left guessing what the best algorithm might be.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are returning either k or 0, correct?

Then this is the way to do it:

```
int[] p = new int[] {1,4,4,5,1,3,6};
int[] q = new int[] {2,1,3,1,6,4,3};
int k =4.

void notNested()
{
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    // Find the kth smallest number in the array.
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    for (int p1 : p)
    {
        if (pq.size() < k)
        {
            pq.add(p1);
        } else if (pq.peek() > p1)
        {
            pq.poll();
            pq.add(p1);
        }
    }

    int ksm = pq.poll();
    // For each q, compare against kth smallest only.
    for (int q1 : q)
    {
        if (q1 >= ksm)
        {
            results.add(k);
        }
        else
        {
            results.add(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not care about the order of the items in `p`, right? This might be fine, although I understood OP meant the _first_ k elements smaller `q[i]`.

Comment: It is only returning the smallest k items in p, because that determines whether it is possible or not.  If the question requires the "first" k elements smaller than q[i], then without knowing the constraints, it's difficult to optimize it without the nested loop, as we can potentially blow out memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of *different* elements in `p` is relatively small compared to the *total* number of elements, the following might work. If, however, there are many different elements, or even all elements are different, then it will be much slower.

- create a `Map` mapping elements to their indices, e.g. `[1,4,4,5,1,3,6]` would become `{1: [0,4], 4: [1,2], 5: [3], 3: [5], 6: [6]}`
- from that map, get the lists of indices for all elements smaller than the current element from `q`
- put those into a Heap, or Priority Queue, sorted by the next unused index for that element
- pop lists from the heap, get the first index, and put them back onto the heap for the next index until you get `k` indices

If there are many repeated elements (and only then), this may somewhat reduce the complexity. For `P` elements in `p`, `d` of which being distinct, `Q` elements in `q`, and `k`, this should have complexity of `O(P + Q*(d+k*log(d)))` (`P` for creating the map, and `d` for selecting the lists and `k` heap operation with `log(d)` for all the `Q` queries).